# How to use DatabaseExtensions.CreateSqlStringAccessor method inside DB transaction?

Tags: c#, .net, enterprise-library

I need to use DatabaseExtensions.CreateSqlStringAccessor method inside the database transaction. 
my code is bellow. to map parameters i have separate method "getParameter".

Is there any method with transaction parameter

```
public MyClass GetMyClassById(int cId, DbTransaction trn)
    {
        String sSql = "SELECT * FROM MY_CLASS";
        IDataParameter[] parameters = new IDataParameter[1];
        parameters[0] = this.getParameter("cId", DbType.String, cId);
        IParameterMapper paramMapper = new ParameterList(parameters);
        IRowMapper<MyClass> myClassRowMapper = MapBuilder<MyClass>.MapAllProperties().Build();

        var results = MyDB.CreateSqlStringAccessor<MyClass>(sSql, paramMapper, myClassRowMapper).Execute().ToList();
        return results.ElementAtOrDefault<MyClass>(0);

    }
```